# using aggregation in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have following records in mongodatabase.

```
> db.student.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ca76140e468ba197e50c23"), "name" : "pratik", "subject" : "maths", "marks" : 68 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ca762b0e468ba197e50c24"), "name" : "pratik", "subject" : "biology", "marks" : 96 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52ca77a90e468ba197e50c25"), "name" : "pratik", "subject" : "maths", "marks" : 40 }
```

From this record I want to know the total marks obtained for just maths subject.
Here is what I have tried,but I don't know what is going wrong in the following query.

```
db.student.aggregate(
{$match: { 'subject': "maths"}},
{ $group : { _id :{ name:"$name",subject:"$subject",marks:"$marks" },
            total: { $sum : "$marks"}}
})

{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "name" : "pratik",
                                "subject" : "maths",
                                "marks" : 40
                        },
                        "total" : 40
                },
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "name" : "pratik",
                                "subject" : "maths",
                                "marks" : 68
                        },
                        "total" : 68
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Could you please let me know what has went wrong in the above query along with the correct answers.
Also suggest me the appropriate guide to use the aggregation module so that I can use it efficiently.I am beginner to aggregation module of mongo database.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `marks` field in the group within the `_id`. It will group upon mark scores then which is useless to you, instead you want:

```
db.student.aggregate(
    {$match: { 'subject': "maths"}}, 
    {$group : { 
        _id :{ name:"$name", subject:"$subject" }, 
        total: { $sum : "$marks"} 
    }}
);
```

Comment: This has worked for me. Thanks Sammaye.Could you please suggest me the appropriate guide to use the aggregation module so that I can use it efficiently.I am beginner to aggregation module of mongo database and bit confused.

Comment: @user1961408 A good one is normally the zip code example: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/ it should teach you most things